# IE9: Div within a Div, where the inside div has a bigger width

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have a website where there is a div within a container div that has a bigger width than the container div.

In Firefox & Chrome, this inner div does not increase the width of the parent div. However, in IE the opposite is true.

I need to make it so the container div does not increase it's width due to the larger div within it.

Is this even possible in IE?

Many thanks

Comment: [`overflow-x: hidden`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen in IE9 if you specify the standards compliant mode.

Try putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="width: 250px; height:150px; background-color: #ff0">
<div style="width: 500px; height:100px; background-color: #f00">
blaaah
</div>
</div>
```

Displays: 
[image: Screenshot showing the working code. Before anyone comments: html, head and body tags are optional in HTML5]

However if you run the same code in Quirks Mode (Via the F12 developer menu) it does expand the outer `div`. You will find enabling standards compliant mode will greatly increase Internet Explorer's compatibility with your website!

Comment: Thanks guys - I had a doctype issue as described above. I did have one declared, but I had a php script that echoed content above the declaration!